# Why SSL certificate handling in selenium stopped working?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, ssl-certificate

I created a selenium test for a website with no SSL certificate few weeks ago. I disabled certificate errors as shown in Selenium documentation. This is my WebDriver setup:

```
options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
options.add_argument('ignore-certificate-errors')
options.accept_insecure_certs = True
driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)
```

It used to work just fine for Chrome, Edge, Firefox and Safari. Now I can't perform the test on any browser because of this error (I looked it up in the network tab of the inspect tool):

> SSL_ERROR_BAD_CERT_DOMAIN

When I run it on Firefox I can see the added arguments in new tabs as in the picture: [Firefox with arguments in url](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tK4gI.png)
After few seconds the first tab redirects to the tested site. That has never happened to me before.I haven't made any changes to my code. The website did not change as well.

I tried updating Selenium from 4.11 to 4.13.

Then I tried adding

```
options.add_argument('allow-insecure-localhost')
```

to the setup.

I also tried to simplify the problem, but the inspect tool returns the same certificate error even for the most basic test. When checked on non-automated browser, the requests are being sent correctly.

Comment: Post a [mre] including information on the server software and configurations. Anyway, I don't believe it worked before because Firefox has no ```ignore-certificate-errors``` option.